# Draggable div setting options in script

Tags: draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

What could cause the draggable option to not be set for an element.

I have these jquery settings.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

and try to turn off the draggable option in code like this.

```
     editable.parent().draggable({disable: true});
     editable.parent().draggable("option", "disable", true);
```

editable.parent() does find the right element, but the draggable option isn't turned off.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure the selector is ok

2)

```
.draggable("disable")
```